# Your app has been suspended: Non-compliant version of aliyun SDK which has code to download/install apps from unknown sources outside of Google Play

Tags: android, sdk, video-streaming, publish, google-play-console

**Issue: Google play suspended app with below reason:**

> Your app contains content that doesn't comply with the **Device and
> Network Abuse policy**. We found your app is using a non-compliant
> version of **Aliyun SDK** which **contains code to download or install
> applications from unknown sources** outside of Google Play.

**Below is the Play console email image, describing detailed reasons for policy violation.**
[image]

App uses Aliyun dependencies as below:

```
implementation 'com.aliyun.video.android:upload:1.6.6'
implementation 'com.aliyun.video.android:core:1.2.2'
implementation 'com.aliyun.video.android:AlivcFFmpeg:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.aliyun.video.android:svideopro:3.22.0'
implementation 'com.aliyun.race:AliyunRace:1.2.0'
```

Ref 1: [Short video SDK : Release notes](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/en/vod/developer-reference/release-notes)

Ref 2: [Integrate the short video SDK for Android](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/en/vod/developer-reference/integrate-the-short-video-sdk-for-android)

After searching I found two references which have all above dependency versions except SDK `com.aliyun.race:AliyunRace`.
I have tried to search for this issue in the release history of these SDKs but have not found anything.

I have come across some doubts regarding this issue:

1. How to find which Aliyun dependency is causing this issue?
2. No documentation found for `com.aliyun.race:AliyunRace` dependency. Is this dependency not maintained now or has been replaced with some other dependency?
3. If I update all Aliyun dependencies to the latest version, can I release the APK on the play store channel other than production to check if this issue has been resolved?

Please suggest other possible ways to approach this issue & also share important reference to solve this issue.